# How to prevent laptop's touchscreen from being smudged by finger prints/oil and getting scratched by finger nails?

Tags: laptop

For our smart phones we have screen protector and I am not sure if those are also made for laptops. At least where I live, I have never seen anyone use a screen protector for laptops. Whenever I use touchscreen (I almost always, always use keypad. but sometimes I have no choice and I have to use the screen).

I am always afraid that screen will get scratched (I don't have long nails) and there are always finger prints on screen,or oil from hands afterwards. I can't easily just clean the screen then, I have to always use some kind of wipe for it and it's not always convenient. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a touch screen laptop that you try to avoid touching but sometimes have to?

Have you considered, for the times where you need to do a single tap/drag rather than a multi finger one, bending your fingers and touching the screen with the middle finger's "elbow" (the part most people knock on a door with)

Your finger tips do the most work in your life, touching food, scratching your nose etc and end up the most oily/dirty. By contrast the skin on the tops of your fingers tends to stay cleaner and drier. I tend to use this part of my finger to work the touchscreen oven/touch sensitive hob on the kitchen when I've just finished cutting food and dumping it in a cookware so I don't end up with e.g juices and sauces smeared all over the place

Alternatively, consider using sticky backed Velcro strips to attach a piece of microfibre cloth to your laptop (on the palm rest maybe) so you can rub your fingers clean before touching the screen. You can also detach it and use it to wipe the screen or/and chuck it in the washing machine when it's too dirty. Being microfibres it shouldn't need any chemicals added to do an adequate job but if you choose to use a bit of water it also does a good job of drying the water off without leaving water marks

An alternative, more of a screen protector- if they don't sell specific ones where you are you might be able to obtain sheets of clear plastic used by school teachers when they want to write on an overhead projector but not actually write on the device itself. Such things may have gone the way of the dinosaur with the advent of whiteboards, smartboarss and computer driven projectors but they still exist. A google search for "acetate sheets" should produce what I mean. They can be trimmed to size and rubbed on your jumper to generate a bit of static electricity which may help them stick to the screen if tape doesn't do it for you. Alternatively a tiny amount of clean water on the screen then spread the sheet out, will also help a bubble free adhesion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same kind of stylus you could use on a smart phone.
Then you will not touch the screen with your fingers, so you will not make the screen dirty.

Nails do not have that much of an influence on the screen but with a stylus you will not have your nails near the screen.